# RxUI IViewFor<T> fails, demands IActivationForViewFetcher

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I'm trying out ReactiveUI in wpf.  A requirement is to run it over a  style framework that provides its own Window object I have to derive from, hence I'm trying to implement IViewFor. I've been following the docs/handbook and here is my Window partial

```
public partial class MainWindow : IViewFor<MainWindowViewModel>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty
        .Register(nameof(MainWindowViewModel), typeof(MainWindowViewModel), typeof(MainWindow));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
        this.WhenActivated(disposable =>
        {
            this.Bind(ViewModel, x => x.WindowText, x => x.TestBlock.Text)
                .DisposeWith(disposable);

        });
    }

    object IViewFor.ViewModel
    {
        get => ViewModel;
        set => ViewModel = (MainWindowViewModel)value;
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get => (MainWindowViewModel) GetValue(ViewModelProperty);
        set => SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value);
    }
}
```

which produces this error -

> System.ArgumentException: 'Don't know how to detect when ModernReactive.MainWindow is activated/deactivated, you may need to implement IActivationForViewFetcher'

Since the only documentation I can find about this says it's about porting RxUI to a new platform *or* was fixed two years ago, this has left me somewhat disheartened.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

This is more likely caused by not including a NuGet reference to `ReactiveUI.WPF`

Make sure you are using `PackageReference`, if you are using `packages.config` it will likely make your life harder.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference

Comment: I actually don't know whether this is correct or not because in the end, I didn't need to extend the base object this way.  Took a lot of trying loads of different stuff, but it RxUI managed it all on its own.

Answer (score 2):

For the case somebody has the problem with AvaloniaUI. You need to use `UseReactiveUI()` in `BuildAvaloniaApp()`.

```
using Avalonia;
using Avalonia.ReactiveUI;
using System;

namespace app;

class Program
{
    // Initialization code. Don't use any Avalonia, third-party APIs or any
    // SynchronizationContext-reliant code before AppMain is called: things aren't initialized
    // yet and stuff might break.
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args) => BuildAvaloniaApp()
        .StartWithClassicDesktopLifetime(args);

    // Avalonia configuration, don't remove; also used by visual designer.
    public static AppBuilder BuildAvaloniaApp()
        => AppBuilder.Configure<App>()
            .UsePlatformDetect()
            .LogToTrace()
            .UseReactiveUI(); // <===================== add this line
}
```

Similarly, on Android:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashActivity : AvaloniaSplashActivity<App>
{
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
    }

    // add this override
    protected override AppBuilder CustomizeAppBuilder(AppBuilder builder)
        => base.CustomizeAppBuilder(builder)
            .UseReactiveUI();
}
```